# BigQuery Query Syntax getting path of URL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a row with URL column.

I like to break the URL into domain and path. I can do domain by using Domain(URL) in BigQuery syntax.

My question is How do I get the path of the URL ?

e.g. 
http://www.somedomain.com/X/Y/abc

I want to get X, Y and abc as separate columsn.

Comment: good feature request, looking into it

Comment: Thanks. I am doing a like to like comparison with Microsoft Log Parser.

Comment: Unfair comparison - BigQuery is better (or not? I'd love to see your final tally). It could certainly benefit from having this feature - thanks for the request!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use REGEXP to extract what you need

```
SELECT Regexp_extract(URL,r'^http://www(?:[^/]*)/(.*)') as full_path,
 Regexp_extract(URL,r'^http://www(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*/){0}([^/]*)') as full_path0,
 Regexp_extract(URL,r'^http://www(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*/){1}([^/]*)') as full_path1,
 Regexp_extract(URL,r'^http://www(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*/){2}([^/]*)') as full_path2,
 Regexp_extract(URL,r'^http://www(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*/){3}([^/]*)') as full_path3,
FROM 
(Select 'http://www.somedomain.com/X/Y/abc' as URL)
```

And regarding comparison with MS log parser.

- Log Parser runs straight on the logs  flat files while in BQ you need
  to load it 1st.
- Log parser runs on a dedicated machine while BQ runs as a cloud
  service (many machine, you don't care how many...)
- You'll find that performance wise BQ does things faster and with
  no concern of yours in regard to the resources    available for
  processing. (Log parses can run multi-threads only as number of
  available CPU Units, and consumes a lot of cache of the machine it
  runs on )
- the regex functions in BQ gives you all the flexibility in
  extracting any pattern of data from the logs.

Enjoy

Comment: Is it possible to use variables in Big Query ?

Comment: Unfortunately no... (I think they have some feature requests for it) Our workaround is an offline process (python) that generates a query based on template & replaces some placeholder strings in it.

Comment: Awesome. For the domain part, one can add: Regexp_extract(pageurl,r'^(?:http:\/\/|www\.|https:\/\/)([^\/]+)')

Answer (score -1):

ga_sessions has hits leaf tables that breaks up your URL automatically

With your example of

```
http://www.somedomain.com/X/Y/abc

hits.page.pagePathLevel1 will have 'www.somedomian.com/'
hits.page.pagePathLevel2 will have '/X/'
hits.page.pagePathLevel3 will have '/Y/'
```

Comment: The question is generic to BigQuery, and not to Analytics data in BigQuery.